# OpenTK.Core - GL.NamedBufferStorage raises System.AccessViolationException

Tags: c#, opengl, opentk

## Intro

I am following this [tutorial](https://dreamstatecoding.blogspot.com/p/opengl4-with-opentk-tutorials.html) to learn how to use OpenGL in C#. Everything ran fine until this part: [OpenGL 4 with OpenTK in C# Part 5: Buffers and Triangle](https://dreamstatecoding.blogspot.com/2017/02/opengl-4-with-opentk-in-c-part-5.html?showComment=1502710784890#c8620478420843666070). I am not using the exact same OpenTK as the one used in the tutorial. I am using this version that is compatible with .NET Core here: https://www.nuget.org/packages/OpenTK.NETCore/

## Issue

When I run the program, my console shows the following stacktrace:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
   at OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.GL.NamedBufferStorage[T2](Int32 buffer, Int32 size, T2[] data, BufferStorageFlags flags)
   at Minecraft.RenderObject..ctor(Vertex[] vertices) in d:\users\user\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\Minecraft\Minecraft\RenderObject.cs:line 22
   at Minecraft.Game.OnLoad(EventArgs e) in d:\users\user\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\Minecraft\Minecraft\Program.cs:line 42
   at OpenTK.GameWindow.Run(Double updates_per_second, Double frames_per_second)
   at Minecraft.Program.Main(String[] args) in d:\users\user\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\Minecraft\Minecraft\Program.cs:line 183
```

## Code

My code very closely matches the one found on the tutorial:

### RenderObject.cs

```
using System;
using OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL;

namespace Minecraft
{
    public class RenderObject : IDisposable
    {
        private bool initialized;
        private readonly int vertexArray;
        private readonly int buffer;
        private readonly int verticeCount;

        public RenderObject(Vertex[] vertices)
        {
            this.verticeCount = vertices.Length;
            this.vertexArray = GL.GenVertexArray();
            this.buffer = GL.GenBuffer();

            GL.BindVertexArray(this.vertexArray);
            GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, this.buffer);

            GL.NamedBufferStorage(
                this.buffer,
                Vertex.Size * vertices.Length, // the size needed by this buffer
                vertices, // data to initialize with
                BufferStorageFlags.MapWriteBit); // at this point we will only write to the buffer

            GL.VertexArrayAttribBinding(this.vertexArray, 0, 0);
            GL.EnableVertexArrayAttrib(this.vertexArray, 0);
            GL.VertexArrayAttribFormat(
                this.vertexArray,
                0, // attribute index, from the shader location = 0
                4, // size of attribute, vec4
                VertexAttribType.Float, // contains floats
                false, // does not need to be normalized as it is already, floats ignore this flag anyway
                0); // relative offset, first item

            GL.VertexArrayAttribBinding(this.vertexArray, 1, 0);
            GL.EnableVertexArrayAttrib(this.vertexArray, 1);
            GL.VertexArrayAttribFormat(
                this.vertexArray,
                1, // attribute index, from the shader location = 1
                4, // size of attribute, vec4
                VertexAttribType.Float, // contains floats
                false, // does not need to be normalized as it is already, floats ignore this flag anyway
                16); // relative offset after a vec4

            GL.VertexArrayVertexBuffer(this.vertexArray, 0, this.buffer, IntPtr.Zero, Vertex.Size);

            this.initialized = true;
        }

        public void Render()
        {
            GL.BindVertexArray(this.vertexArray);
            GL.DrawArrays(PrimitiveType.Triangles, 0, this.verticeCount);
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            this.Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }

        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                if (this.initialized)
                {
                    GL.DeleteVertexArray(this.vertexArray);
                    GL.DeleteBuffer(this.buffer);
                    this.initialized = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Program.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using OpenTK;
using OpenTK.Graphics;
using OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL4;
using OpenTK.Input;

namespace Minecraft
{
    class Game : GameWindow
    {
        public Game() :
            base(
                800,
                600,
                GraphicsMode.Default,
                string.Empty,
                GameWindowFlags.Default,
                DisplayDevice.Default,
                4,
                5,
                GraphicsContextFlags.ForwardCompatible)
        {
            this.VSync = VSyncMode.On;
        }

        private int program;
        private List<RenderObject> renderObjects = new List<RenderObject>();

        protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnLoad(e);

            Vertex[] vertices =
            {
                new Vertex(new Vector4(-0.25f, 0.25f, 0.5f, 1 - 0f), Color4.HotPink),
                new Vertex(new Vector4(0.0f, -0.25f, 0.5f, 1 - 0f), Color4.HotPink),
                new Vertex(new Vector4(0.25f, 0.25f, 0.5f, 1 - 0f), Color4.HotPink),
            };
            this.renderObjects.Add(new RenderObject(vertices));

            this.CursorVisible = true;

            this.program = this.CreateProgram();
            GL.PolygonMode(MaterialFace.FrontAndBack, PolygonMode.Fill);
            GL.PatchParameter(PatchParameterInt.PatchVertices, 3);

        }

        {...}

        /// <summary>
        /// Compiles all shaders
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns> An OpenGL program </returns>
        private int CompileShader(ShaderType shaderType, string path)
        {
            // 1. Create the shader object
            var shader = GL.CreateShader(shaderType);
            // 2. Read the shader source from file
            var src = File.ReadAllText(path);
            // 3. Assign the shader source to the shader object
            GL.ShaderSource(shader, src);
            // 4. Compile it so OpenGL can use it :)
            GL.CompileShader(shader);
            // Check if anything was written to the info log during the 
            // compilation of this specific shader and write it to Debug log
            var info = GL.GetShaderInfoLog(shader);
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(info))
            {
                Debug.WriteLine($"{nameof(GL)}.{nameof(GL.CompileShader)} [{shaderType}] had info log: {info}");
            }
            return shader;
        }

        private int CreateProgram()
        {
            var program = GL.CreateProgram();
            var shaders = new List<int>();

            shaders.Add(
                this.CompileShader(
                    ShaderType.VertexShader,
                    @"Components\Shaders\1Vert\vertexShader.vert"));
            shaders.Add(
                this.CompileShader(
                    ShaderType.FragmentShader,
                    @"Components\Shaders\5Frag\fragmentShader.frag"));

            foreach (var shader in shaders)
            {
                GL.AttachShader(program, shader);
            }
            GL.LinkProgram(program);

            var info = GL.GetProgramInfoLog(program);
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(info))
            {
                Debug.WriteLine($"{nameof(GL)}.{nameof(GL.LinkProgram)} had info log: {info}");
            }

            foreach (var shader in shaders)
            {
                GL.AttachShader(program, shader);
                GL.DeleteShader(shader);
            }
            return program;
        }

        protected override void OnRenderFrame(FrameEventArgs e)
        { 
            base.OnRenderFrame(e);

            this.Title = $"FPS: {1.0f / e.Time:0}";

            GL.ClearColor(new Color4 { A = 1.0f, R = 0.1f, G = 0.1f, B = 0.3f });
            // Clear all the buffers to start drawing afresh
            GL.Clear(ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit | ClearBufferMask.DepthBufferBit);

            GL.UseProgram(this.program);

            foreach (var renderObject in this.renderObjects)
            {
                renderObject.Render();
            }

            // Present the rendered scene to the user
            this.SwapBuffers();
        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // the 'using' idiom guarantees proper resource cleanup.
            // We request 60 UpdateFrame events per second, and unlimited
            // RenderFrame events (as fast as the computer can handle).
            using (Game game = new Game())
            {
                game.Run(60);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am very new to OpenGL so I do not understand what this is about. Please help me. Thank you :)

---

It seems that my problem is related to which version of OpenGL was used. Because I am developping on a laptop with NVIDIA Optimus, it was choosing to use my Intel HD Graphics 4600 which only has OpenGL 4.3, while the OpenGL function used is part of OpenGL 4.5.

What I did was force Optimus to launch all applications using the NVIDIA GPU which support OpenGL 4.5. Now my program launches with no problems.

My question now is:

1. Is there a way to *programmatically* force Optimus to use NVIDIA GPU instead of Intel's? If so, how can I keep my program cross-platform?
2. Is there a way to do what I am trying to do here using an older version of OpenGL? Not everybody has OpenGL 4.5 I believe

Comment: `GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, this.buffer);` This isn't your problem (odds are good that OpenTK simply hasn't been updated with GL 4.5), but if you're using direct state access to modify the buffer... why are you binding it to the `ARRAY_BUFFER` binding? It's completely useless if you're using DSA functions. Also `GL.EnableVertexArrayAttrib` that's not a DSA function. You want `EnableVertexArrayAttrib`.

Comment: @NicolBolas ah yes, you are right. The official OpenTK that uses .NET Framework/Mono has OpenGL 4.6 while OpenTK.NET Core only has OpenGL 4.4 . I will try with the official OpenTK then.

Comment: When I print the GLVersion it shows OpenGL 4.3. Is it possible to force it to use a newer version?

Comment: If your implementation doesn't support a version of OpenGL, it doesn't support it. You could try updating the driver if a newer one is available.

Comment: @NicolBolas Does the OpenGL version depend on the GPU used? The version 4.3 is used when Intel integrated chip is running my program. How can I force it use my NVIDIA card? Normally I would right click on the executable and clikck on Run with high performance graphics (aka NVIDIA) but here when I build I get a .DLL not an .EXE (has something to do with the project being a .NET Core project). Is it possible to choose which GPU to use in the program?